# Why bcrypt always returns different results?

Tags: laravel, bcrypt, password-hash

Consider the following typescript:

```
$ ./artisan tinker
>>> bcrypt('123456')
=> "$2y$10$YLswQefA6JXTYMM5nH90we9siAtG71I1/LMa5XIkplCF32EMtXmKK"
>>> bcrypt('123456')
=> "$2y$10$LoakjerqalqFxI6r.BR.x.K1fycqWS59Xqfj.pblSzlPNLOcbWa/6"
```

Why is that?

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin First, `./php` won't generally work. Second, why not leave it as it was (`./artisan`)? That would suggest that one can make `artisan` executable and run it more easily. For those who don't know that yet.

Comment: I'd appreciate it if you'd explain when you downvote ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a different salt used each time. A [random salt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) is mixed in to the hash to prevent [precomputed hash tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) from being used. Without salting, an attacker would be able to detect common strings like `password123` due to their recognizable hashes. Salting ensures the hashes aren't predictable.

Comment: And also would immediately know if two or more people have the same password

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on rainbow tables, if that's what you mentioned? I gather, they're not just mappings between passwords and their hashes? Smart hash tables?

Comment: That's exactly what they are: mappings between passwords and their hashes. Without salting, an attacker could precompute the hashes for many common passwords.